# Determine if Checkbox is Checked using jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check checkbox checked property using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property-using-jquery)

What is the correct way of accessing a checkbox to check if it's checked?  Is it necessary to first check if that element exists in the DOM and then see if is checked or not?

Comment: See [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property-using-jquery

Comment: @Vega Given an appropriate DOMElement (which *must* exist), but not the most tidy way in jQuery.

Comment: @pst In the FM doesn't say if I first need to check if the element exists, and that was my doubt.

Answer (score 40):

You would use the checked selector along with the is method of Jquery

```
if($('#chkbox').is(':checked')){

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can see if the checkbox is checked by using the following condition.

```
   if( $("input:checked").length == 1 ) {
           //Checkbox is selected and Do stuff here
       }
```